# Sending empty {} after form "post" with pug in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, pug

I'm trying to pass form data from login page to signin page via post using fetch with this pug code:

```
form(id="form-login")
    input(type="text", name="email", value="", placeholder="Tu email")
    br
    input(type="password", name="password", value="", placeholder="Tu contraseña")
    br
    input(type="submit" value="Conectar")
script.
    const formLogin = document.querySelector('#form-login');
    const formData = new FormData(formLogin);

    formLogin.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        console.log('Form Data: ', formData);
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
        })
    });
```

The problem is an empty req.body reaching to signin.. After trace it gives this console.log

```
Form Data:  FormData {}
```

and also an undefined req.body.
If I comment this script and just send it through form adding `action="/signin" and method="post"`, it works and the answer is printed, but calling `storage.setItem({ token: <token> })` returns an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`
I'm wondering why this script is not sending the data... can't figure out... so any help will be much apreciated.

Signin function:

```
function signIn (req, res) {    
    if (!req.body.email) return res.status(200).send({message: 'No recibo el usuario'})

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {

        if(err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err })
        if(!user) return res.status(404).render('login', { title: 'Intenta loguearte de nuevo' })

        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) => {
            if (error) return res.status(500).send({ message: error })
            if (!isMatch) {
                return res.redirect('login')
            } else {
                req.user = user
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'Te has logueado correctamente',
                    token: service.createToken(user)
                })
                //$window.localStorage.setItem({token: service.createToken(user)}); // NO WORKS
                return res.body = service.createToken(user) // TRYING THIS WITHOUT KNOWLEDGE ABOUT WHAT AM I DOING :O
            }
        })                 
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

****EDIT****
As @MichałSałaciński suggest, commenting first `.then res.json()....` At least gives a response, but still don't undestand what's hapenning here and in order to learn properly and make things better, also hope someone can explain how to correctly do stuff like this.

```
  Response: body : ReadableStream
locked : false
__proto__ : Object
bodyUsed :   false
headers :  Headers
__proto__  :  Headers
ok :  true
redirected :  false
status : 200
statusText: "OK"
type  :   "basic"
```

Comment: I have zero experience with pug. Is it normal to chain two `then` calls right after each other like that?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know the promise is inside the script tag, so shouldn't be in conflict with pug at this point. 
Yes you can chain .then.Check docs here ->  [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Finally, did you find a solution?? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 4):

So I was having the same issue where the POST request from my pug form was sending back an empty `{}` as the `req.body` object. The code was a simple create action using these:

**bookController.js**

```
exports.createBookForm = (req,res) => {
  res.render("create_book_form", { title: "Add A New Book"})
}

exports.createBook = (req,res) => {
  const reqFields = ["title", "author"];

  for (let i = 0; i < reqFields.length; i++) {
    const field = reqFields[i];

    if (!field in req.body) {
      const message = `Missing ${field} in the request body`;
      console.log(message)
      return res.status(400).send(message)
    }
  }

  Book
    .create({
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      summary: req.body.summary
    })
    .then((book) => {
      res.status(201).json(book.serialize())
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

And the create book form:

```
block content
  h1 Add a Book
  h3 Do use real details. Otherwise, what's the point?

  form(method="POST" action="/books")
    div.form-group
      label(for="title") Title:
      input#title.form-control(type="text", placeholder="Small Gods" name="title")
      label(for="author") Author:
      input#author.form-control(type="text", placeholder="Terry Pratchett" name="author")
      label(for="summary") Summary:
      textarea#summary.form-control(type="text", placeholder="God is turtle, world is flat" name="summary")
      div.form-group
        button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit" role="submit") Add Book
```

What finally fixed getting the actual req.body to show up for the POST action was adding (within server.js)

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Let me know if this works for you. Took me a couple hours to come to this conclusion and I hate seeing questions go unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You should move "new FormData" inside "send" event listener. Also, there's missing comma after type="submit", but overall, the problem got nothing to do with pug :)

```
form(id="form-login")
    input(type="text", name="email", value="", placeholder="Tu email")
    br
    input(type="password", name="password", value="", placeholder="Tu contraseña")
    br
    input(type="submit",value="Conectar")
script.
    const formLogin = document.querySelector('#form-login');

    formLogin.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    const formData = new FormData(formLogin);

        console.log('Form Data: ', formData);
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
        })
    });
```

Comment: No works for me, fixed missing comma and moving `const formData` inside the function nothing changes, still stuck... and someone gifts a -1... Have your best day ever guy!

Comment: Yeah, downvoting here is strange, as the question seems perfectly valid. If it still doesn't work, try to return "return res.json();", also try with & without "body: formData"

Comment: Ok, tried it, and get this response:
`Response {type: "basic", url: "http://192.168.1.104:3000/signin", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true…}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers
__proto__
:
Headers
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"basic"
url
:
"http://192.168.1.104:3000/signin"`
Look like inside the response.body is nothing also:
`body
:
ReadableStream
locked
:
(...)
__proto__
:
Object
bodyUsed
:
false`