# HOW TO: send and get "formdata" with pug and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, pug

got this form in pug:

```
extends layout

block login
    form(id="form-login")
        input(type="text", name="email", value="", placeholder="Tu email")
        br
        input(type="password", name="password", value="", placeholder="Tu contraseña")
        br
        input(type="submit" value="Conectar")
```

I'm trying to handle it with this script right after above code (properly idented):

```
script.
    const formLogin = document.querySelector('#form-login');

formLogin.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    const formData = new FormData(formLogin);
    console.log('Contenido de Formulario: ', formData);
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        //body: formData
    })
    //- .then(function(res) {
    //-     res.json();
    //- })
    .then(function(data) {
        //console.log(data)
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
    })
});
```

Handler function is receiving an empty `req.body`.

This question extendes [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080316/sending-empty-after-form-post-with-pug-in-node-js)
I hope someone knows what's happening here, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the console output of formData?

Comment: an empty object {}

Comment: ok this is your problem. can you move  const formLogin = document.querySelector('#form-login'); line inside submit callback. and try to console formLogin. check whether you are able to find form?

Comment: If I do this. formLogin will no longer exist, you mean declare it before and then asign it a value inside the function?

Comment: ok did you do console.log(formLogin)? are you able to see form DOM in console?

Comment: Yes, log shows html like content with the form.

Comment: Finally, did you find a solution?? I have the same problem!

Comment: @Andynedine If I remember... I needed "body-parser" library in order to send POST data from Express. I can share the code if needed.

Comment: Yes, please @AdolfoOnrubia!! I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: PUG code:
`body
        h1 Crear Post
        form(action="/api/post" method="post")
            input(type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titulo")
            br            
            input(type="textarea" name="name" placeholder="Nombre del autor")
            br     
            input(type="submit" value="Crear Post")`

Comment: unfortunately, @AdolfoOnrubia I still have the problem. I think that body-parser don't work. I tried with app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:<true|false>})) and much more, without success. My req.body always is {}

Comment: We can't use new FormData(formLogin) because FormData forces to multipart/form-data and is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be the answer since I fixed it from this.

```
block login
    form(id="login" action="/signin" method="post")
        input(type="text", name="email", value="", placeholder="Tu email")
        br
        input(type="password", name="password", value="", placeholder="Tu contraseña")
        br
        input(type="submit" value="Conectar")
```

Route code:

```
router.post('/signin', usercontrol.signIn)
```

Controller code:

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const service = require('../services')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')


function signUp (req, res) {
    console.log('Registrando usuario: ', req.body)
    const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        displayName: req.body.displayName,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    user.save((err) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send({ message: `Error al crear el usuario: ${err}`})

        return res.status(200).send({ token: service.createToken(user) })
    })
}

function signIn (req, res) {    
    console.log('Tratando de loguear con req: ', req.body.email)

    if (!req.body.email) return res.status(200).send({message: 'No recibo el usuario'})

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
        console.log('Respuesta de búsqueda', user)

        if(err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err })
        if(!user) return res.status(404).render('login', { title: 'Intenta loguearte de nuevo' })
        console.log('Respuesta de user: ', user.email)

        let userPwd = req.body.password
        let dbPwd = user.password
        console.log('Pwd Usuario: ', req.body.password, 'Pwd Base de Datos: ', user.password)

        bcrypt.compare(userPwd, dbPwd, (error, isMatch) => {
            if (error) return res.status(500).send({ message: error })
            if (!isMatch) {
                console.log('La contraseña No es correcta !isMatch: ', !isMatch)
                return
            } else {
                req.user = user
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'Te has logueado correctamente',
                    token: service.createToken(user)
                })
            }
        })        
    })
}

module.exports = {
    signIn,
    signUp
}
```